# How to fix Menu for Nevigation pages in Master Detail page for all platform(android and uwp)

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have designed master detail page for my application.
Here I past screentshots of my application.
[Homepage overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRvuD.png)

I use data grid view to show my data.

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk9ce.png)

but, I don't want to hide my Menu.I fix that in my application home screen for uwp app only.

So after fix that I want to show my data in datagridview for rest of the screen.

I want to unhide Menu.

Is that posiible using master detail page design.

How can I do it, Please any suggestion or code example.

advance thanks.

Customized screen what I want:-

[CustomScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jTsY.png)

Comment: Hello Developers any suggestion regarding this

Comment: Hi, do you mean that want to hide or show Menu in Master Detail Page when app is running?

Comment: yes....exactly.....How can I do it...Actally my project requirments is that fixed Menu .

Comment: Okey, you can custom a MasterDetailPageRenderer to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **MasterDetailPageRenderer** in **UWP** solution as follows:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppMasterDetailDemo.Views.MainPage), typeof(CustomMasterDetailRenderer))]
namespace AppMasterDetailDemo.UWP
{
    public class CustomMasterDetailRenderer: MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MasterDetailPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.CollapsedPaneWidth = 0;
                Control.CollapseStyle = Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific.CollapseStyle.Partial;
                Control.MasterToolbarVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                Control.DetailTitleVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                Control.MasterTitleVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                Control.ContentTogglePaneButtonVisibility =
     Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Xamarin Forms, set as follows can hide the Menu button.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Or modify the `false` to `true`, can show again.

The effect:

[image]